# Exporting a component inside an asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I use to react and nearby. I need to export a component, but I don't have the right to put it in a function

```
function Index(){
    
}
export default Index
```

You must receive a request, but you can only write to a variable if the function is asynchronous.
I had to create a wrapper

```
async function asy(){ 
     
    const data = await fetchData()

    function Index(){

    }
    export default Index
}

asy().then(r => r);
```

Now I can't export the component.

I found a different solution, but it doesn't work either.

```
function Index(){
    return async function asy(){
        //async function. 

        const data = await fetchData()
        return <React.Fragment/>
    }
}

export default Index
```

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think I fully understand your question but here is what I understood,
You want to return a component after making an async request to retrieve data.

I would go for something like this:

```
function Index() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);
  
  retrieveData = async () => {
     // Retrieve your data
     setData(retrievedData);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    retrieveData();
  }, [])
  
  if (data != null) {
   return <YourComponent />
  } else {
   return null
  }
}
```

This code will call the retrieveData function each time this component is mounted